# Dropdown menu background hover only around text

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

Im quite new to this so very sorry for the basic questions! I'm currently trying to create a dropdown menu within my navigation bar and having a little trouble trying to trouble shoot why my background hover in my sub-menu only displays from the left of the box to the end of the text and not across the complete box.
I have a felling it has something to do with the padding in my anchor?
Thanks and appreciate all the help!

```css
/*Bottom Navigation*/

    .BottomNav{
     background: #fac2ad;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     }
    .BottomNav li{
     display: inline;
     }
     .BottomNav a{
     float: left;
     color: #000;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: macho,sans-serif;
     font-weight: 900;
     font-style: normal;
     max-width: 40%;
     display: block;
     padding: 15px;
     font-size: 2rem;
     text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);
   
    }
    .BottomNav:hover .dropDown:hover .dropButton{
    background-color: white;
    transition: 0.8s ease-out;
    }
    .dropDown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .dropDown .dropButton{
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: macho,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);
    }
    .dropdownContent{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdownContent a{
    float: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdownContent a:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .dropDown:hover .dropdownContent{
    display: block;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="BottomNav">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
          <div class="dropDown">
            <button class="dropButton">
              Adoptions
              <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdownContent">
              <a href="/adoptionDogs.html">Dogs</a>
              <a href="/adoptionCats.html">Cats</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <li><a href="Why select adoption.html">Why select adoption?</a> 
           </li>
          <li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Image of the problem I'm having
[image: Image of the problem I'm having]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have check your code & i have fixed some issues in your code.

```css
.BottomNav {
    background: #fac2ad;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.BottomNav li {
    display: inline;
}
.BottomNav a {
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: macho,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    max-width: 40%;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 53%);
}

.dropDown {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}


   
.dropDown .dropButton {
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: macho,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 53%);
}

.dropDown:hover .dropdownContent {
    display: block;
}

.dropdownContent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdownContent a {
    float: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.dropdownContent a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav class="BottomNav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
      <div class="dropDown">
        <button class="dropButton">
          Adoptions
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdownContent">
          <a href="/adoptionDogs.html">Dogs</a>
          <a href="/adoptionCats.html">Cats</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <li><a href="Why select adoption.html">Why select adoption?</a> 
       </li>
      <li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! This worked just as needed. Appreciate your time.

Comment: it's' my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix your issue and in order to fix that I removed some of the unnecessary code or the code which were creating issue.
Also it is an advice that if you know how to use flex-box then try to avoid "Floats". It will be much easier with flex and grids.

Here is my solutions, I have tried to comment out all the changes made, if I missed any then I'm really sorry for that,  hope this helps.

```css
/* Bottom Navigation */
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.BottomNav{
 background: #fac2ad;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 }
 /* ADDED FLEX PROPERTY TO MENU TO GET HORIZONTAL LAYOUT */
 #menu{  
   display: flex; 
 }
.BottomNav li{
 list-style: none;
 /* display: inline;  REMOVED*/
 }
 .BottomNav a{
   /* float: left;  REMOVED */
 color: #000;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: macho,sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-style: normal;
 /* max-width: 40%; REMOVED */
 display: block;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 2rem;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);

}
.dropDown .dropButton{
font-size: 2rem;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: black;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: macho,sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
font-style: normal;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 15px;
text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527);
}
.BottomNav:hover .dropDown:hover .dropButton{
background-color: white;
transition: 0.8s ease-out;
}


.dropdownContent{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdownContent a{
  /* float: none; REMOVED */
color: #000;
/* padding: 12px 16px; REMOVED */
text-decoration: none;
/* display: block;  REMOVED */
text-align: left;
}


/* .dropdownContent a:hover{
background-color: #ddd;
} */
/* HOVER PROPERTY ADDED TO li INSTED OF ANCHOR TAG */
.dropdownContent li:hover{
background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropDown:hover .dropdownContent{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="BottomNav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
      <div class="dropDown">
        <button class="dropButton">
          Adoptions
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdownContent">  
        <li><a href="/adoptionDogs.html">Dogs</a></li> <!-- Wrapper the anchor inside li -->
         <li> <a href="/adoptionCats.html">Cats</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li><a href="Why select adoption.html">Why select adoption?</a> 
       </li>
      <li><a href="Contact us.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Hi @sameer, Thanks for the input! This works well! Thanks for the suggestion on using flex-box  instead of float. Will defiantly learn how to use it next time!